# Issue with call_user_func_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, array-merge

Having a bit of a problem in combining arrays...this works:

```
    $un[0] = array("0:0:0");
    //$un[1] = array("1:1:1");
    $flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $un);
```

If I uncomment the second $un, it still works (and combines the two).

Now, if I say, change that from a hard-coded array into an array from a DB query (I know mysql  ext is being deprecated):

```
            $u = mysql_query("SELECT `XX` FROM `XX` WHERE `XX` = '".$XX."' AND `XX` = '0'");
            $un = mysql_fetch_row($u);
```

I run the query through PhpMyAdmin and it works. So when I add `$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $un);` after the `mysql_fetch_row` it returns an error:

PHP Warning:  array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in *****LOCATION*****

And I cannot seem to figure out why...since the DB query should spit out $un[0], $un[1], etc., exactly as the code that works, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_merge excepts one or more array's - what you actually do is to pass array_merge all cells of the row as an param. This looks i.e. like `array_merge('row1', 'row2',...)`

So what you want is perhabs something like this

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array($un));
```

Comment: +1 you beat me and your explanation is a lot better then mine